# PDF artefacts when trying to print using Adobe reader

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I have Adobe Reader 10.1.10 (latest that supports my language), and whenever I try to print something, it ruins the file. I tried printing to PDF (basically save), or open with PDFFactory, all is corrupted.

Here is how it looks before print:
[image]

And here is after:
[image]

Also notice that it thickens the font a bit, and removes some text (top left corner, it removes '17')

I tried following [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/kb/thin-white-dark-lines-stitching.html) help guide, but with no luck.

Files:

- [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5jORv16xomiOGpRaE5IeXZhUHU3X3FYVldBd3FIc24wdXFR/view?usp=sharing) is the original PDF.
- [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5jORv16xomiQTMzTU90N3JaakpScXoyeHBmVVFTckM5cEE0/view?usp=sharing) is after I print it to file or to actual printer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure you have all fonts specified in the PDF on your system.
2. Try [printing as an image](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/quick-fix-print-pdf-image.html), rather than using the available fonts.
3. Try a third-party PDF viewer such as the free [Sumatra](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) or [PDF-XChange Viewer](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer). I've found Sumatra offers more accurate rendering, but PDF-XChange Viewer opens large files more rapidly.

Hopefully, one of these methods will work for you.